# DomDocument produces an exception when it encounters an anchor in an html file?

Tags: php, domdocument

When I am loading my html file and the dom finds an anchor for instance

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/page?utm_source=NSLGARNIER&utm_medium=19082012&utm_campaign=SUNSHINE_MOMENTS" style="color:#ababab;text-decoration:none;">Facebook</a>
```

it returns me with an error

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() [domdocument.loadhtmlfile]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in files/emailing_garnier543/emailing_garnier/emailing_garnier.html, line: 13 in C:\wamp\www\emailingtool_new_old\process.php on line 42

The line 12 in process.php consists of the following line

```
$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile($file);
```

It seems it does not accept the ? in the url..
How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

http://codepad.org/eRYubHSA

```
<?php
$string = '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/page?utm_source=NSLGARNIER&utm_medium=19082012&utm_campaign=SUNSHINE_MOMENTS" style="color:#ababab;text-decoration:none;" >Facebook</a>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom->loadHTML($string);

var_dump($dom->saveHTML());
```

Comment: It worked fine. I would also like to know why this happened ? The "?" in a url is valid as far i as know

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to the `?` but to the two `&`. They should be `&amp;`. [Check it](http://codepad.org/lEH5tDfS).